# should I be using passenger in dev to match prod for a ruby on rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

Should I be using passenger in dev to match prod for a ruby on rails project?  (as opposed Webrick)

Noting I'll be deploying to dreamhost which uses passenger.

(Also if yes, does it have it's own web-server or do I need to install one?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a passenger staging server on your production machine. Use same configuration as pro server.

This has just saved my bacon. A recent upgrade we recently pushed broke application and took me a week to get sorted. Fortunately production server continued to function which we found prob.

Use capistrano multistage to manage the same.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to (mostly). But there might be cases where things can go wrong due to the mismatch between production & dev environment. Using staging environment will catch such issues.

If you want to test things like SSL, then webrick wont work. You need apache/nginx(or other web servers) to use passenger. I also noticed that there is no significant difference in the performance between the two options

Comment: for simple rails apps then might be easier to stick to webrick until there is a point I see a need to migrate DEV to passenger (and have to go through an apache install).   Any pros/cons re debugging between the options?

Comment: Agreed. A staging server that has the identical environment as the production server is the best way to handle this, imo.